# Styles not applied in view without it's master layout - ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a razor master layout `_Master.cshtml` and I include `Master.css` in it. 
I also have a `Home.cshtml`  and `_Master.cshtml` is it's layout.
In home I have a view `Event.cshtml` - this view does not have any master page setup.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<style>
    .boxStyle{...}
</style>
<div class="boxStyle">
    ...
</div>
```

This works. But I want to move `.boxStyle` to the `Master.css`
And when I move it there it doesn't work anymore.
But if I add bellow code to `_Master.cshtml` then works. But I need it in css file.

```
<style>
    .boxStyle{...}
</style>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move the css from the `Event.cshtml` to the `Master.css` you have to place a link tag in the  `Event.cshtml` like that.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/Master.css">
```

Of course you need to add to the Event.cshtml also the basic html tags

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/Master.css">
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>

  ..

  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: So there is no other way? Because this "event" is just a box on the page. Like "People you may know" box on linkedIn.

Comment: If this page is rendered alone you have to provide it the basic html structure. If this page is rendered inside another page (ex. loaded inside a div via ajax) you can omit this structure and output only the content.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your Event.cshtml file has no master layout? If it is in it's own folder you can add a _ViewStart.cshtml file to that folder and add

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/SomeFolder/_Master.cshtml";
}
```

to this file. (SomeFolder is the folder that Event.cshtml is in) Then you can add a new master layout _Master.cshtml with this in it:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/Master.css">
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    @RenderBody()
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```